# Location textbox lookup MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a service/control that allows a user to type a location into a textbox. The control would offer a list of suggestions that in a dropdown style that the user could select from.

Ideally there would be a callback that offers the gps position of the selected location.

This is for a .net MVC application.

Does anyone know of a control like this? I think the new google maps app on iphone uses a system similar to this.

Thanks

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this jquery plugin that works a treat....

http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/